# Get the child of a random ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database structured like that, I want to get the children of the push generated id, for example `correcta`.

I have done this until now but it never gets anything:

```
mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions");
mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String key=dataSnapshot.getKey();
            DatabaseReference questiondatabase=mdatabase.child(key);

            questiondatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Map<String, String> itemPrice = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

                    txtpregunta=itemPrice.get("pregunta");
                    txtopcion1=itemPrice.get("opcion1");
                    txtopcion2=itemPrice.get("opcion2");
                    txtopcion3=itemPrice.get("opcion3");
                    txtopcion4=itemPrice.get("opcion4");

                    Map<String, Integer>correctagetter = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

                    correcta=correctagetter.get("correcta");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: Firebase]

Thanks

Comment: You've included a screenshot of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a value listener to a node, you get a snapshot with all data under that node. You don't have to attach further listeners to get data deeper in the tree.

Instead you just have to iterate over the children of the snapshot:

```
DatabaseReference questionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions");
questionsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot questionsSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot questionSnapshot: questionsSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String questionKey = questionSnapshot.getKey();
      String pregunta = questionSnapshot.child("pregunta").getValue(String.class);
      String opcion1 = questionSnapshot.child("opcion1").getValue(String.class);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
});
```

I *highly* recommend that you take the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs).

Comment: Thanks man, i have another doubt, How can i retrieve that "Correcta" as an int?

Comment: `Integer correcta = questionSnapshot.child("correcta").getValue(Integer.class);` Did you take the codelab?